# How to edit scrolling text so it's always visible?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, squarespace

Right now, the scroll bar on my about page (site is [here](https://coyote-coconut-z39a.squarespace.com/about). Password to view is Hello2021) has blank space after the string of text, before it starts it's next rotation. How can I make it so the text is always visible and scrolling, with no blank space?

```html
 <div class="scroll">BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW</div>
```

```css
.scroll{ overflow: hidden!important;
position: relative!important;
 -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);  
 transform:translateX(100%);
 -moz-animation: scroll 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: scroll 15s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll 15s linear infinite;}

@-moz-keyframes scroll {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }

}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll  {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
#page {overflow-x:hidden}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the desired effect is not achievable with Css alone. A solution using [dynamic-marquee](https://github.com/tjenkinson/dynamic-marquee) library could be implemented like:

```html
<!-- This code block must be in head -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dynamic-marquee@1.3.2/dist/dynamic-marquee.js"></script>

<!-- This code block must be in body and above the 3rd block -->
<div id="marquee"></div>

<!-- This code block can be in the body or footer -->
<script>
    var $marquee = document.getElementById("marquee");
    var marquee = (window.m = new dynamicMarquee.Marquee($marquee, {
      rate: -100
    }));
    window.l = dynamicMarquee.loop(
      marquee, [
        function() {
          return "BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW • BOOK NOW";
        },
        function() {
          return "Another line of important text";
        }
      ],
      function() {
        var $separator = document.createElement("div");
        $separator.innerHTML = "&nbsp|&nbsp";
        return $separator;
      }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. Can you tell me where I should add the code in Squarespace? I've tried a few places (code blocks/footer code injection/additional CSS/etc and it doesn't seem to display regardless

Comment: i don't know squarespace but it seems they have good documentation. i updated the code to better reflect the places the parts are expected to be dropped into.